# .NET MVC check if query is not null and show partial view

Tags: sql, linq

I want to check if my query returns rows, and if so show a partial view.

Here is what I have so far:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetMembership(int id)
    {
        var membership = from m in db.CustomerEnrollment
                      where m.CustomerID == id && m.CustomerTypeID == "1" && m.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow
                      orderby m.StartDate
                      select m;
        return PartialView("_GetMembership", membership);
    }
```

So now I just need to check if there are rows.

Would this be close or am I way off?

```
        if (membership != null)
        {
            return PartialView("_GetMembership", membership);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if(membership.Any()){...}
```

Comment: Working now! I needed to add return null; below the if statement.